# Javascript and HTML width in %

Tags: javascript, c#, html, html-table

I have an html text for example:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" width="50%" id='AAA' border='1' cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%">
      <div align="center">Nr. rd.</div>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <div align="center">Indicator</div>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
      <div align="center">Valoare</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="5%">
      <div align="center">A</div>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <div align="center">B</div>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
      <div align="center">1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract width from table `$("#AAA")` using Javascript. The value I want must be in %.

Comment: Answer edited to give the width in percent;

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JS**

You should use the `.offsetWidth`for the element divide by `innerWidth` of the window

```
var width = document.getElementById('AAA').offsetWidth;
var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
var widthPercent = width / winWidth * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var width = $("#AAA").width();
var window = $( document ).width();
var percent = ((width/window) * 100);
```